# php count wordand remove

Tags: php, cpu-word

how to remove some word on url inp php?

URL : /hiaz/0.1.1/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=153&tracking=507b790fadc48

i just want :
 tracking=507b790fadc48

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Are you just trying to retrieve some of the request values?  Or are you trying to rewrite the URL?

Answer (score 4):

If you have the full url stored in the var $myurl:

```
$result = substr($myurl, strrpos($myurl, "tracking"), strlen ($myurl) );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `$_GET` if you are working in the `index.php`. Alternatively, if you wish to grab whole query string, you can use `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`

Answer (score 0):

What you have is

```
$url = /hiaz/0.1.1/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=153&tracking=507b790fadc48
```

What you want is

```
$newurl = /hiaz/0.1.1/index.php?tracking=507b790fadc48
```

First extract part of url upto "?" character.
Then extract the tracking part and combine.

```
$part1 = substr($url,0,strpos($url,'?'));
$part2 = substr($url,strpos($url,"tracking"),strlen($url)-strpos($url,"tracking"));

$newurl = $part1 + $part2;
```